# Trouble moving a multilingual Prestashop site in Google Search Console

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, prestashop

I've got a multilingual Prestashop store named example.ch and want to move it to example.com, preserving the SEO efforts.

I've set up 301 redirects to the new domain.

My properties are registered as `https://example.ch` and `https://example.com`. Because the site is multilingual, accessing the root of the site automatically sends me to my browser's preferred language (i.e. example.com/en). At step 2 of the move request ("Confirm that 301-redirects work properly"), GSC tells me "The old site redirects to example.com/en, which does not correspond to the new site you chose.".

While I understand what this means, I'm puzzled as to how to get it straight. Shall I create one property per language for the old site (eg. example.ch/en, example.ch/fr) and one per language for the new site and make one move request per old site/new site pair? Wouldn't I lose my SEO this way as the properties would be new?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set in localization/configuration/ Set language from browser: NO so the default language you will choose will not have redirect. I have a couples of Prestashop and there is no redirect, at least I did not note.
Also Set default country from browser language to NO. If this will not create problem to your users of course.

Comment: Thanks Massimiliano! I understand how this would work for a single language. But as I see it, Google will think our multilingual site has become monolingual, won't it?

Comment: Hi, I don't think so because from the main (default) language you will have the links to the other languages. So Google will follow the links. Just the browser will not redirect automatically depending on location or language setting.

Comment: Massimiliano, I've tried your solution on my dev store and the language suffix remains.

Comment: Hi, I recheck my shops and they don't have the suffix. Both shops are still under construction but what I think about your suffix maybe can depend on the theme. My theme is default-bootstrap version 1.0 and your one?

Comment: Sorry about the lag! My theme is [Coffee House Store](https://addons.prestashop.com/en/food-restaurant-themes/24643-coffee-house-store.html).

Comment: Hi, I don't know that theme. If it is free I will try it and tell you... as soon

Comment: Hi, is not free I cannot try it.